# Mark file as critical in git

Tags: git, svn

Under my git project, I want to mark a certain file as critical so that if anyone commits to critical files I can be notified under that. is there any way to mark files as critical with git or add custom properties to a certain file.

With Svn we can easily assign custom properties(let say critical) I want a similar option with Git repos.

Comment: That depends heavily on how your workflow is organized and where you want that to happen. Do you have a decentralized pattern? A centralized one? If so what are you using? Is it sufficient to have that notice if you check out a file? Should everyone be notified?

Comment: A centralized pattern. I want notification only if somebody commits to that file.

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840184/how-can-i-automatically-be-warned-if-a-specific-file-changes) on stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes but where to do you want that notification to happen in your setup? Also what are you using for centralization because having a bare repo somewhere and having full blown GitHub, GitLab etc. might provide very different options. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169787/github-file-change-notification).